# T-SQL: Ensure expression evaluation order in WHERE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, where-clause

I'm sure someone can quickly solve this for me. I'm sure I'm not the first to ask this question, but i didn't find anything similar yet.

Having the following WHERE statement:

```
WHERE boolean_expression1 OR boolean_expression2 OR subquery_count > 0
```

Is this executed this way?:

- if (boolean_expression1 = true) -> exit with true
- else if (boolean_expression2 = true) -> exit with true
- else -> execute subquery?

I mean: Is the subquery only executed if the preceeding expressions both are false?
And if not, is there any way I can ensure this?

Because the subquery could be quite expensive in my case.

Thx in advance,
Chris

Comment: SQL Server does **NOT** make any promises about the order of evaluation - and you cannot force any order, either.

Comment: How about CASE WHEN-expressions? Could you imagine a statement for this OR example:
WHERE (@GlobalSearch = 1 OR @SomeCount = 0 OR (subquery) >= @SomeCount)

Comment: check the execution plan. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359702/how-do-i-obtain-a-query-execution-plan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WHERE case when boolean_expression1 then 1
else case when boolean_expression2 then 1
else when subquery_count > 0 then 1 end = 1
```